# Writing a sentence

Tags: grammar

can I change the sentence “a white elephant was given to the king.” into the sentence “The king was given a white elephant.” I guess it may be possible, and if it is right, which one is the more often used? I really appreciate your knowledge and kind explanation in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*A white elephant was given to the king* is in the pattern: *Direct Object - Passive Verb - Indirect Object*.

*The king was given a white elephant* is in the pattern: *Indirect Object - Passive Verb - Direct Object*.

Both of these constructions are grammatical. The question about which pattern is more often used is one I cannot answer. But in my opinion this is of theoretical value only. In the real world of conversation and communication, it is important to understand the context and the communicative intent of the speaker.

If we imagine a context in which the speaker is telling a story about animals that are given away to various people, then we are more likely to encounter a sentence such as *A white elephant was given to the king.*

If, on the other hand, the story is about the king and the gifts he received, then we are more likely to hear *The king was given a white elephant*.

---

The term given to the organizational choices made by speakers in communicating their message is *[information  structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_structure)* or *information packaging*. According to the theory of *information structure* the *topic* or *theme* is what is being talked about (in our case, the elephant and the king respectively). The topic is often, but not always, also the grammatical subject of the sentence, as it is with the elephant and king sentences.